# How do install whole LLVM suite (including Clang, LLDB, and LD) and its include/lib files from terminal?

Tags: apt, software-installation, compiling

How do install whole LLVM suite (including Clang, LLDB, and LD) and its include/lib files from terminal?

I notice that, if I download the Clang binaries, then utilities like llvm-config are not installed. Neither, can I locate the associated include and lib files for writing LLVM applications, like compiler passes.

I've attempted to install LLVM suite by building source, but ninja fails after around 1000 builds.

So, I would like to use apt-get's functionality for installing LLVM suite on my system, so that I can follow the tutorials on the LLVM-site, which assume you have installed the include and lib files, but also utilities like llvm-config.

Can anyone tell me how to accomplish this?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install clang llvm`? AFAIK `llvm-ld` has been removed

Comment: Why has it been removed?

Comment: Will this command also install include libraries, so that the complete API is obtained?

Answer (score 0):

I found the best answer on the llvm website https://apt.llvm.org/

Below I install llvm with clang a variable for ${LLVM_VERSION}. You can swap out a different number if you want.

#### General Install Example

(don't forget to replace ${LLVM_VERSION}

```
wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh
chmod +x llvm.sh
sudo ./llvm.sh ${LLVM_VERSION} all
sudo ./llvm.sh all
```

#### Install LLVM-14

```
wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh
chmod +x llvm.sh
sudo ./llvm.sh 14 all
sudo ./llvm.sh all
```